# How to remove gaps between bars with unequal widths in Matplotlib bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a metrit-order supply curve bar chart in matplotlib (or another python plotting library).

The width of each bar represents that observation's size (in this case, installed rooftop solar), the y axis indicates cost, and the X-axis represents the *cumulative* size of all observations at, or below the specific cost. This creates a supply curve that looks something like this:

[image]

Note that the widths of each bar are not the same, and that the observations are sorted so that no bar will ever be shorter than any bar to its left.

Does functionality like this exist in any plotting package, or should I write a script that dynamically calculates the necessary position for each bar dependent on the width of bars on either side?

Comment: You do not need to center the bars at their coordinates, maybe for such curves it's better to have them left-aligned, such that the width is equal to the difference between successive points.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution I threw together, although I feel like a `gaps=0` option probably exists in matplotlib that I can not find documentation for.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

cost = [1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4]
width = [1.0, 5.0, 10.0, 15.0, 10.0]
y_pos = [1,2,3,4,5]
colors = ['red','blue','green','red','blue']
bars = ['A','B','C','D','E']

relative_positions = []
relative_position = 0
previous_width = 0
for w in width:
    print(w, w/2)
    relative_position = float(relative_position + (previous_width/2) + (w/2))
    print(w, relative_position)
    previous_width = w
    relative_positions.append(relative_position)


plt.bar(relative_positions, cost, width=width, color=colors)
plt.xticks(relative_positions, bars)
```

[image]